# Loading data for an ListView after click event in an item of another listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I want loading data for an ListView after click event in an item of another listview
For Example, I have listview A: A B C
And after click in A will have D E F
click in B will have G H I
and C will have J K L

The thing is I have to load it from the Startup event so it won't have Null Reference Exception event. Then I loaded it but it didn't show up the result I want (Only the data from start up event). Moreover, I debug the code and figure it out that it has the data but the data on startup don't let them show.
Note: The other ListView is show on Popup
So, How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ObservableCollection<int> Chars { get; set; }

private async void ClickItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      await Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate () 
      {
           for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
           {
                Chars.Add(Chars.Count + 1);
           }                
       }, DispatcherPriority.Input);
}
```

xaml

```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Chars}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding }" Click="ClickItem"></Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
```